# What is causing my redirect loop?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am using mod_rewrite to create prettier URLs for a website I am working on. However a redirect loop is being caused for my css and js folders.

Here is what is in my .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .tpl
AddCharset UTF-8 .js
AddCharset UTF-8 .css
AddCharset UTF-8 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /guildtree/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_'-]+)/(.*)$        characters.php?realm=$1&name=$2     [NC]
```

My CSS is being redirected to

```
http://localhost/guildtree/css/error
```

and my JS is being redirected to

```
http://localhost/guildtree/js/error
```

My images are all coming up broken as well, even though the path to them is correct. Going to the images directly results in a redirect loop as well.

```
http://localhost/guildtree/images/roster/error
```

Is there anything that stands out as the reason to be causing this loop? Thanks.

Update:

The issue with the CSS and images have been resolved. The JS still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a redirect loop, your images are probably getting caught by the characters.php route. Add some exclusions to your rule:

```
RewriteBase /guildtree/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_'-]+)/(.*)$        characters.php?realm=$1&name=$2     [NC]
```

Additionally, you may have a relative/absolute pathing issue. If your links are relative, they will be changed by the new path and you need to add a:

```
<base href="/guildtree/">
```

Or whatever the base path should be for all your relative links.

Comment: That fixed up the issue with the CSS and the images. Not sure why the JS isin't working though. I thought it was a redirect loop because my browser stated it was a redirect loop.

Comment: @akari check to make sure the script links are not relative.

Comment: I am able to view the source and click on the links to access the files, I don't get an error any more so I'm not entirely sure what is going on.

Comment: Actually it appears to be one specific JS file that is no longer working. localhost/guildtree/js/jquery.tablesorter.js I can access it just fine, but it is no longer working.